# MP4 video from Android phone can't be played in Windows

Tags: windows-7, video, android, video-conversion

I took a video on my Samsung Galaxy S2 (Android), it's about 3GB and it can be played on the phone. But after transferring it to the PC is does not play when opened with VLC, QuickTime, Windows Media Player.

I tried to convert it to AVI using "Pazera free Mo4 to AVI" converter, but it fails before being converted.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

**mediainfo:**

```
updated:
Complete name                    : C:\281.mp4
Format                           : MPEG-4
Format profile                   : 3GPP Media Release 4
Codec ID                         : 3gp4
File size                        : 3.05 GiB
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to AVI in the first place? AVI is a horrible container that even supports less than MP4. Have you installed any Codec pack for Windows (like CCCP, K-Lite)? Please check [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en)'s output for the file and include it in your post.

Comment: i have pasted the mediainfo's output

Comment: Hm, that's weird. Do you have another PC to check? Maybe it's a problem with the file size itself.

Comment: but the phone is able to play the file, so i think its a codec issue..

Comment: Try media player classic (MPC) shipped with K-Lite and many other coded packs. It will give you very detailed error information which will help us help you. It seems to me that you have a damaged file that cause the mp4 splitter on your computer to fail. You may want to copy the file again.

Answer (score 1):

Transfer using the "Mass Storage" option in "USB Settings" and it will work fine! The Samsung Kies option is what is messing up files over 2GB or so.

[Source](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s2-international/370632-transferred-video-pc-refuses-play.html)

Comment: Incredible that this was never upvoted before! (also unfortunate that Mass Storage option was removed from Android many years ago) However I have an old Xperia Z3 that still works great for video recording in FullHD, and I could not get the resulting file to play in Windows until I copied it via Mass Storage. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is how you transfer the video from your phone . Don't just copy and paste especially with this file size, it will get corrupted  somewhere in between the process. use the Windows file transfer or the program that came with your phone or file transfer you cant find in the internet

Comment: Why do you believe that copy and paste is less reliable than other data transfer mechanisms?

Answer (score 1):

When I transferred videos from my android phone to my Windows 7 computer, some of them would play audio only using Windows media player. I assumed that the files that played only audio were corrupted. Later, however, I was flipping through files in a folder with a mixture of jpeg and mp4s from my phone using photo gallery, and all of the videos played! Apparently, photo gallery was using a different driver (or codec?) than media player. At this point, I could see that the videos that didn't play using media player were shot in portrait orientation while the ones that played were shot in landscape orientation. My goal was to load these videos into Movie Maker for editing, but it had the same problem as media player, playing only audio from the portrait mode videos.

After a lot of poking around with different players and software, I found that I could load the portrait video into Muvee Turbo Video Stabilizer, rotate the video, stabilize it, save it, and then Movie Maker would load the newly saved file. I could then rotate it back to portrait orientation so it was right side up and edit as usual.

This trick would probably work with any software that will load and play the portrait video and allow you to rotate. Then you will have a video that you can use with other software that may not be able to handle the original file.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to install a codec pack. [This](http://www.windows7codecs.com/) is quite a good one. You can also choose from which codecs to pick.

Comment: i have installed the codec and tried to play it with VLC and it does not work....

Comment: @krisdigitx Did you check to install all codecs? Did you try it with WMP? It could also be that you have to select the codecs in VLC.

Comment: yup i installed all the video codecs..i tried it with WMP also and it does not recognise